# Go lang keep function alive

Tags: while-loop, go

I have a go function which will do some logic after the Channel have received some logic.

My problem is I want the function to keep alive after it has done the logic. My thinking is

that I will add a endless while loop in the function. However, I am wondering whether this is

a good technique. My Code is as follows:

```
func process(channel chan string, sid string) {
    inputSid := <-channel

    // check if sid exist in process pool
    if strings.EqualFold(sid, inputSid) {
        fmt.Println("Got message", sid)

         //the code that I added to make this function alive
         for {} 

    } else {
        channel <- sid

        //the code that I added to make this function alive
         for {} 

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to keep-alive the function?

Answer (score 7):

For future reference:

A better way to keep alive a function is to use an empty `select` statement which will block a Go routine indefinitely. As opposed to an empty `for` statement, it does not consume CPU time doing so.

```
select { }
```

Comment: +1. I didn't know that! (the CPU consumption part) :D

Comment: Good tip but using range over the channel is a better answer

Answer (score 6):

Just use the standard "Go way". You can `range` over a channel until it is closed:

```
for sid := range channel {
    // do stuff
}
```

It will continue until the channel is closed. Adding a "wait loop" like that is asking for trouble.